# Change password in java

Tags: java, servlets, dao

I am designing an application where once user logged in, he can change the password.
For changing password, I need 3 details:

1. Old Password
2. New Password
3. Confirm Password

In servlet layer I am setting

```
 user.setPassword(oldPassword);
```

method I am implementing in DAO layer

```
 changePassword(User user, String newPassword)
```

The problem I am facing is that I am not able to validate old password.
Whatever the old password is, I am able to change to a new one.

I think what the problem might be is that it is taking the old password directly from the 
session. Any suggestion would be very helpful. Thankyou..!!

Comment: Please share the DAO code?

Comment: How can you not validate the old password? Validating a password is a pretty big part of logging in :)

Comment: Perhaps you are missing a layer between your servlet layer and the DAO layer which does the business logic (checking old password and setting new one)?

Comment: I have implemented the service layer which encrypt the new password and sends it to DAO layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same method or make a similar one to the method you use for logging in...